# error:avro parsing & modifying json

Tags: json, avro

I am having this json

{

```
   "cid":"8CUC4FKD1"
```

}

and schema as

{

```
"type" : "record",
"name" : "MyClass",
"namespace" : "com.test.avro",
"fields" : [ {
"name" : "tagId",
"type" : "string",
"default" : "def1"
 }, {
"name" : "cid",
"type" : "string"
} ]
}
```

but it is giving exception "expected field not found : tagId"
I searched a lot and found that i should use "nullable/default" etc but that also didnt work.It is not taking even default value.
I think there is problem in my code which is converting json to avro record like following:-

static byte[] fromJasonToAvro(String json, String schemastr) throws Exception {

```
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
    Schema schema = Schema.parse(schemastr);

    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);
    DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<Object>(schema);
    Object datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
    GenericDatumWriter<Object>  w = new GenericDatumWriter<Object>(schema);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Encoder e = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);
    w.write(datum, e);
    e.flush();

    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

I am giving json & above schema as parameter to this method.

Comment: Not sure why the post is tagged as Hadoop, but if you're within a Hadoop environment you can use Hive, Pig, Spark, etc to read in JSON and write out Avro more easily that dealing with the base Avro classes yourself

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to read the data using the "writer" schema, in this case  it only contains cid field. This is  not needed when you read avro files which contain the writer schema. The following example read the data with the writer schema and print the data with your expected schema

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.*;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\"cid\":\"8CUC4FKD1\"}";

        String strWriterSchema = "{\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\"type\" : \"record\",\n" +
                "\"name\" : \"MyClass\",\n" +
                "\"namespace\" : \"com.test.avro\",\n" +
                "\"fields\" : [ {\n" +
                "\"name\" : \"cid\",\n" +
                "\"type\" : \"string\"\n" +
                "} ]\n" +
                "}";

        String strSchema = "{\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\"type\" : \"record\",\n" +
                "\"name\" : \"MyClass\",\n" +
                "\"namespace\" : \"com.test.avro\",\n" +
                "\"fields\" : [ {\n" +
                "\"name\" : \"tagId\",\n" +
                "\"type\" : [\"string\"],\n" +
                "\"default\" : \"def1\"\n" +
                " }, {\n" +
                "\"name\" : \"cid\",\n" +
                "\"type\" : \"string\"\n" +
                "} ]\n" +
                "}";
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
        Schema schema = Schema.parse(strSchema);
        Schema writerSchema = Schema.parse(strWriterSchema);

        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(writerSchema, din);
        GenericDatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<Object>(writerSchema);
        reader.setExpected(schema);
        Object datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
        System.out.println(datum);
    }
}
```

outout

```
{"tagId": "def1", "cid": "8CUC4FKD1"}
```